# C++ vector max_size();

Tags: c++, vector, max-size

On 32 bit System.

1. `std::vector<char>::max_size()` returns 2<sup>32</sup>-1, size of `char` — 1 byte
2. `std::vector<int>::max_size()` returns 2<sup>30</sup>-1, size of `int` — 4 byte
3. `std::vector<double>::max_size()` returns 2<sup>29</sup>-1, size of `double` — 8 byte

can anyone tell me `max_size()` depends on what?

and what will be the return value of `max_size()` if it runs on 64 bit system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply get the answer by

```
std::vector<dataType> v;
std::cout << v.max_size();
```

Or we can get the answer by `(2^nativePointerBitWidth)/sizeof(dataType) - 1`. For example, on a 64 bit system, `long long` is (typically) 8 bytes wide, so we have `(2^64)/8 - 1 == 2305843009213693951`.

Answer (score 33):

`max_size()` is the theoretical maximum number of items that could be put in your vector. On a 32-bit system, you could in theory allocate 4Gb == 2^32 which is 2^32 `char` values, 2^30 `int` values or 2^29 `double` values. It would appear that your implementation is using that value, but subtracting 1.

Of course, you could never really allocate a vector that big on a 32-bit system; you'll run out of memory long before then.

There is no requirement on what value `max_size()` returns other than that you cannot allocate a vector bigger than that. On a 64-bit system it might return 2^64-1 for `char`, or it might return a smaller value because the system only has a limited memory space. 64-bit PCs are often limited to a 48-bit address space anyway.

Comment: `...you'll run out of memory long before then.` I realize this was written in 2010, but even then 4GiB RAM modules were extremely common. Nowadays, most computers have 16GiB as a _minimum_. I feel this blurb should be removed. Also: `64-bit PCs are often limited to a 48-bit address space anyway.` Is this still accurate? I thought Intel processors used _52_ physical address lines nowadays.

Comment: The "run-out of RAM" comment was regarding a 32-bit address space. There might be some CPUs with a 52-bit address space; I know Intel proposed a 57-bit addressing model, but I stand by the statement that they are "often" limited to 48 bits

Answer (score 14):

[max_size()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/max_size/) returns

> the maximum potential size the vector
>   could reach due to system or library
>   implementation limitations.

so I suppose that the maximum value is implementation dependent. On my machine the following code

```
std::vector<int> v;
cout << v.max_size();
```

produces output:

```
4611686018427387903 // built as 64-bit target
1073741823 // built as 32-bit target
```

so the formula 2^(64-size(type))-1 looks correct for that case as well.