# How can I convert a ulong to an positive int?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, integer, bit-manipulation

I have a piece of code that is

```
// Bernstein hash
// http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx           
ulong result = (ulong)s[0];
for ( int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i ) 
{ 
    result = 33 * result + (ulong)s[i]; 
}
return (int)result % Buckets.Count;
```

and the problem is that it's sometimes returning negative values. I know the reason is because `(int)result` can be negative. But I want to coerce it to be non-negative since it's used as an index. Now I realize I could do

```
int k = (int)result % Buckets.Count; 
k = k < 0 ? k*-1 : k;
return k;
```

but is there a better way?

On a deeper level, why is `int` used for the index of containers in C#? I come from a C++ background and we have `size_t` which is an unsigned integral type. That makes more sense to me.

Comment: Why not do the `%` before casting to `int`? Cast `Buckets.Count` to `ulong` instead if necessary. This will still limit you to 31-bit range, but at least it works properly :) As for your deeper question, indices aren't necessarily zero-based in .NET. It's perfectly legal to have an array that goes from -10 to +10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
return (int)(result % (ulong)Buckets.Count);
```

As you sum up values you reach a positive integer number that cannot be expressed as a positive number in a signed 32 bit integer. The cast to int will return a negative number. The modulo operation will then also return a negative number. If you do the modulo operation first, you will get a low positive number and the cast to int will do no harm.

Comment: FYI, `Buckets.Count` is an `int`

Answer (score 1):

While you can find a way to cast this to an `int` properly, I'm wondering why you don't just calculate it as an `int` from the beginning.

```
int result = (int)s[0]; // or, if s[0] is already an int, omit the cast
for ( int i = 1; i < s.Length; ++i ) 
{ 
    result = 33 * result + (int)s[i]; 
}
return Math.Abs(result) % Buckets.Count;
```

As to *why* C# uses a signed `int` for indexes, it [has to do with cross-language compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10040884/781792).