# What is the rationale behind std::allocator::max_size()?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I know that `max_size()` from `std::allocator` is a theoretical limit, but I just tried something and the numbers that I get are just huge; so how I should interpret this numbers and what is the philosophy behind this function ?

my example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>
typedef int8_t Tnum_1;
struct X
{
    template <typename T>
    static void printAllocInfo()
    {
        std::cout << std::allocator<T>().max_size() << "\t Alloc max_size\n";
        std::cout << ((std::allocator<T>().max_size()) / (1024))
                  << "\t Alloc max_size / 1024\n";
        std::cout << (((std::allocator<T>().max_size()) / (1024)) / (1024))
                  << "\t\t Alloc max_size / 1024 / 1024\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    X::printAllocInfo<Tnum_1>();
    return (0);
}
```

it prints:

```
18446744073709551615     Alloc max_size
18014398509481983        Alloc max_size / 1024
17592186044415           Alloc max_size / 1024 / 1024
```

and considering that I just used `int8_t` as the template argument, this means that I can allocate `18446744073709551615 bytes` on my machine ? This number is so big that it starts to loose any practical meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number you quote is of course 2^64 -1, a.k.a the largest 64-bit unsigned integer that can be represented. All `max_size()` indicates that it doesn't support anything larger, not that it supports everyhthing below that size.

It is up to your OS to actually provide this to your program. But since you can compile a program on a different machine that you run it on (including a machine in the distant future), there is no reason to limit `max_size()` to smaller numbers.

**NOTE**: if you read **Table 31 — Allocator requirements** in the C++ Standard, you find the following for an allocator object `a` of type `X`:

> `a.allocate(n)`: Memory is allocated for `n` objects of type `T` but
>   objects are not constructed.
>
> `a.max_size()`: the largest value that can meaningfully be passed to
>   `X::allocate()`

So `max_size` is the largest number of objects, not bytes, that can be allocated.

Comment: maybe I was not that clear in my previous question, let me rephrase it: who uses `max_size` and for what ?

Comment: @user2485710 it is just so as not to break a program running on larger hardware that it got compiled on. 64-bit seems outrageous now, but 640K was once enough for everyone. There is simply no reason to limit `max_size` to current hardware levels if the underlying integer can support 2^64.

Comment: I don't really get it, I really don't get why the C++ standard even bothers to provide such function, this `2^64` is an architectural limit, it's not even tied to an implementation or to a library, it's just telling me that I have a 64 bit machine basically ( and not even in the clearest possible way, maybe they can simply provide a base and an exponent, It would be much easier to read ). I get it, but I don't get what role this information can possibly play.

Comment: Well, it tells you that you're not on a 32-bit system where it's impossible to allocate more than 4GB.

Comment: @user2485710 on 16-bit or 32-bit systems these limits will be actually binding for some allocations, so `max_size` is useful there. And who knows some huge distributed data center in 2050 actually can allocate 2^64 bytes.

Comment: I think you mean 2^64-1.

Comment: This answer is misleading. max_size is so you can estimate the number of elements to put in a container, not the number of free bytes in memory. See this question and its answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813124/c-vector-max-size

Comment: @LincolnMan I don't know about misleading: I never mentioned bytes or objects. But for clarity, I updated the answer with relevant quotes from the Standard. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers provided are incomplete since they only mention number of bytes, but not number of objects.

The [documentation for max_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/max_size) says the function should return *"the maximum theoretically possible value of n, for which the call allocate(n, 0) could succeed,"* where n is the number of objects. It also says that for some allocator implementations it should return

```
std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(value_type)
```

rather than

```
std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()
```

The STL containers (e.g. - `std::vector`, `std::map`, or `std::list`) use max_size to calculate container size in terms of object count, not byte count. Therefore, `max_size()` should not return the number of bytes available on the operating system, but use the number of available bytes to calculate **the number of objects the allocator can hold**.

If you wrote an allocator class for STL containers, you could implement the `max_size()` function like this to provide an accurate object count instead of over-estimating by using `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`.

```
size_type max_size() const
{
    const unsigned long long bytesAvailable = GetTotalAvailableMemory();
    const unsigned long long maxPossibleObjects = bytesAvailable / sizeof(value_type);
    return maxPossibleObjects;
}
```

You can implement the `GetTotalAvailableMemory()` like these functions depending on your operating system. Either will return the number of unallocated bytes which a program's process may use.

```
#if defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)

#include <unistd.h>

unsigned long long GetTotalAvailableMemory()
{
    const long pageCount = sysconf( _SC_PHYS_PAGES );
    const long pageSize = sysconf( _SC_PAGE_SIZE );
    const unsigned long long totalBytes = pageCount * pageSize;
    return totalBytes;
}

#endif

#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN64)

#include <windows.h>

unsigned long long GetTotalAvailableMemory()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX status;
    status.dwLength = sizeof( status );
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx( &status );
    return status.ullAvailVirtual;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/

> This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to known system or library implementation limitations, but the container is by no means guaranteed to be able to reach that size: it can still fail to allocate storage at any point before that size is reached.

As TemplateRex points out, the number you're seeing is 2^64. Basically this is telling you a theoretical limit based on how the software is written, and not that the OS would really honor an allocation so huge.